# Style Triggers not working when object is bound to other object

Tags: wpf, styles

I am having a problem with the style of a few items that are bound to a set of radio buttons. Basically, I have the following code for my styles:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="boxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then I have two radio buttons as shown here:

```
<RadioButton Name="optionA" IsChecked="True">Option A</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Name="optionB'>Option B</RadioButton>
```

And two text boxes as shown here:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource boxStyle}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=optionA, Path=IsChecked}"/>
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource boxStyle}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=optionB, Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

The binding works correctly (when Option A it checked, one box is enabled and the other is not). However, when either of the boxes becomes disabled, it does not follow the style defined above. The background goes to white no matter what I change the style color to.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The color used when disabled is hard-coded in the template as far as i know, you cannot easily change it unless it references a system-color in which case you can override.

The default Aero theme uses a `ListBoxChrome` control, not sure if that can be made to change its background accordingly, it has no template so it might be hard to modify it. You could of course throw it out and use whatever you want (which you can modify).